# A generalization of the difference of squares identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, integer-sequences, symmetric-polynomials

Let us find explicit integer functions for the coefficients of the monomial expansion of
$$
Q \left( x_1, \ldots , x_n \right) = \prod_{\left( \kappa_1, \ldots , \kappa_{n-1} \right) \in \{-1,1\}^{n-1}}{\left( x_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{\kappa_i x_i 
} \right)}
$$

In the following we shall see that these coefficients may be given by a specialization of the elementary vector-symmetric polynomials.

The ancient *difference of squares identity* corresponds to finding the monomial expansion of $ Q \left(x_1, x_2 \right) $, so one may view this question as a certain generalization of the former.

Geometric context for the polynomial (function) $ Q $ can be seen in the [generalized Heron polynomials (proposition 8)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407300) and the [hyperplane threshold arrangements (section 1.2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06595).

## Elementary vector-symmetric polynomials

Let $n,m$ be positive integers. Denote $ X_{m}^{n} \equiv \left( x_{m,1}, \dots, x_{m,n} \right)$ as an ordered commuting alphabet. Denote $\boldsymbol{\lambda} \equiv \left( \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \right)$ as a vector with non-negative integer entries. Denote $\left[ n \right] \equiv \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

The *elementary vector-symmetric polynomial* (also known as *elementary multisymmetric polynomial*) $\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( X_{1}^{n}, \ldots, X_{m}^{n} \right) $ is given by
$$
\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( X_{1}^{n}, \ldots, X_{m}^{n} \right) = \sum_{\substack{ I_1 \cup \dots \cup I_n \subseteq \left[ m \right] \\ \lvert I_1 \rvert = \lambda_1, \ldots , \lvert I_n \rvert = \lambda_n \\ I_1 , \dots , I_n \, \text{2-wise disjoint}}}{\prod_{j \in \left[ n \right]}{} \prod_{i \in I_j}{x_{i,j}}}
$$

Note that if $ \lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_n=0 $ then
$$
\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( X_{1}^{n}, \ldots, X_{m}^{n} \right) = 1
$$
and if $ \lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_n > m $ then
$$
\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( X_{1}^{n}, \ldots, X_{m}^{n}\right) = 0
$$
See Cullis' [Matrices and Determinoids vol. III (section 197, pages 134-135)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.74887) and Rota & Stein's [A problem of Cayley from 1857 (appendix A, appendix B)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379505004416) for further reading and examples, though the definitions given there use different notation than the one employed here. **EDIT:** See Diaz & Pariguan's paper [Quantum Product of Symmetric Functions](https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2015/476926.pdf) (equations (9) to (12), lemma 4) for a definition more in tune with the one given here.

## Q as a Cayley form and its expansion

Suppose now that $ n \ge 2 $.

The polynomial $ Q $ is a product of $2^{n-1}$ linear forms in $ x_1, \ldots , x_n $. A product of linear forms is sometimes known in the literature as a *Cayley form*.

The coefficients of the monomial expansion of a Cayley form can be expressed by elementary vector-symmetric polynomials in the coefficients of the associated linear forms (see section 197, pages  136-137 of Cullis' text linked above; see equation (9) of Diaz & Pariguan's paper linked above).

Denote $ \lvert \boldsymbol{\lambda} \rvert \equiv \lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_n $. Denote $ \mathrm{K}_{m}^n \equiv \left( \kappa_{m,1}, \ldots, \kappa_{m,n} \right) $. Then
$$
Q \left( x_1, \ldots , x_n \right) 
= \sum_{\lvert \boldsymbol{\lambda} \rvert = 2^{n-1}}{\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) \prod_{j \in \left[ n \right]}{x_{j}^{\lambda_j}}}
$$
Note that $ Q $ is a homogeneous of degree $ 2^{n-1} $ polynomial in $ x_1, \ldots , x_n $.

Suppose now that $ n \ge 3 $.

[This MSE answer by Ilya Bogdanov](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3827015/297149) shows that $ Q $ is an even function of $ x_1, \ldots , x_n $, or equivalently the monomials of the polynomial $ Q $ which have an odd exponent have also coefficient $ 0 $. Therefore
$$
Q \left( x_1, \ldots , x_n \right) = \sum_{\lvert \boldsymbol{\lambda} \rvert = 2^{n-2}}{\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) \prod_{j \in \left[ n \right]}{ \left( x_{j}^2 \right)^{\lambda_j}}}
$$

Note that $ Q $ is a homogeneous of degree $ 2^{n-2} $ polynomial in $ x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2 $.

The same answer by Ilya Bogdanov also shows that $ Q $ is a symmetric polynomial.

Recall that the monomial symmetric polynomials in $ x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2 $ of degree $2^{n-2}$ are a basis of the vector space of symmetric polynomials in $ x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2 $ which are homogenous of degree $ 2^{n-2} $.

Let us index the (expanded) polynomial $Q$ in $ x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2 $ by *integer partitions* of $ 2^{n-2} $ (possibly padded with $0$s to the right), or equivalently to write $ Q $ using the monomial symmetric polynomials in $ x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2 $ of degree $ 2^{n-2} $.

Suppose now that the entries of $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ are non-increasing, so  one can identify the vector $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ with an integer partition $\lambda$, by dropping the $0$ entries of $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$, or by padding $\lambda$ with $0$s to the right; specifically
$$ 
\lambda \vdash 2^{n-2} \iff  \lvert \boldsymbol{\lambda} \rvert = 2^{n-2}
$$ Denote $ \operatorname{m}_{\lambda} \left( x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2 \right) $ as the monomial (usual, non-vector-)symmetric polynomial in $x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2$ indexed by the integer partition $\lambda$. Then
$$
Q \left( x_1, \ldots , x_n \right) = \sum_{\lvert \boldsymbol{\lambda} \rvert = 2^{n-2}}{\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) \operatorname{m}_{\lambda} \left( x_{1}^2, \ldots , x_{n}^2 \right)}
$$

### Associated recursive formula

The polynomial (function)
$$ 
q \left( y_1, \ldots , y_n \right) \equiv \sum_{\lvert \boldsymbol{\lambda} \rvert = 2^{n-2}}{\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) \operatorname{m}_{\lambda} \left( y_{1}, \ldots , y_{n} \right)}
$$
admits a recursive formula described generally in [a previous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410099/polynomial-function-defined-recursively-by-a-resultant-is-it-well-defined) or more simply in [another previous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337088/polynomial-defined-recursively-by-a-resultant).

## Integer functions for the coefficients of the form $ \operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) $

### Heron matrix

Let us consider a useful object which deserves its own inquiry.

Consider a matrix $ \mathbf{K} \in \{-1,1\}^{2^{n-1} \times n} $ such that $ \left( \mathbf{K} \right)_{i,j} = \kappa_{i,j} $. Such a matrix is sometimes known in the literature as a (non-normalized) *Heron matrix*.

$ \mathbf{K} $ has some neat and useful properties, such as:

- Its rows are *pairwise* linearly-independent (over a ring not of characteristic $2$).
- $ \operatorname{rank}\left(\mathbf{K}\right) = n$.
- It is a *partial Hadamard matrix*, meaning that
  $$
  \mathbf{K}^{\top} \mathbf{K}= 2^{n-1} \mathbf{I}_{n}
  $$
  or equivalently that any two of its columns agree at exactly half the entries.

- Its last column is $ \boldsymbol{1} $ and all the other columns have exactly half their entries be $-1$.

### Incremented factorial powers

Let us consider another useful object.

Denote $x^{t;u}$ as the $u$-incremented $t$-factorial-power of $x$, where $t$ is a non-negative integer. Then $x^{t;u}$ is given by
$$
x^{t;u} \equiv \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $t=0$} \\
\prod_{i=0}^{t-1}{\left(x-ui\right)}, & \text{if $t \ge 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

#### Examples

The usual $n$-th power of $x$ is given by
$$
x^n = x^{n;0}
$$
The $n$-th falling factorial power of $x$ (using Knuth's notation) is given by
$$
x^{\underline{n}} = x^{n;1}
$$
The $n$-th rising factorial power of $x$ (using Knuth's notation) is given by
$$
x^{\overline{n}} = x^{n;-1}
$$

### Experimental results

Denote $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) $ as the $\#$ of non-zero entries of $ \boldsymbol{\lambda} $, so one may identify $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) $ with the usual *length* of the integer partition $\lambda$ of $2^{n-2}$.

If $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) = 1 $, or equivalently if
$$
\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \left( \lambda_1, 0, \ldots \right)
$$ then
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) & = 1 \\ & = \frac{\left( \lambda_1 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1};2}}{\left( \lambda_1 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1};2}} \frac{\lambda_{1}!}{\lambda_{1}!}
\end{align}
$$
because it corresponds to a product of the entries of any one column of the Heron matrix $ \mathbf{K} $.

If $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda}   \right) = 2 $, or equivalently if
$$
\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \left(\lambda_1 , \lambda_2, 0, \ldots \right)
$$ then experimental evidence suggests that $\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) $ is given by
$$
\frac{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2};2}}{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1};2}\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{2};2}} \frac{\left( \lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} \right)!}{\lambda_{1}! \lambda_{2}!} 
$$
Notice that the latter is a symmetric function in $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$, as is expected.

If $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) = 3 $, or equivalently if
$$
\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \left(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, 0, \ldots\right)
$$ then experimental evidence suggests that $\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) $ is given by
$$
{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} + \lambda_{3};2} \over \prod_{i=1}^{3}{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3  - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{i};2}}} \frac{\left( \lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} +\lambda_{3} \right)!}{\lambda_{1}! \lambda_{2}! \lambda_{3}!} 
$$
Notice that the latter is a symmetric function in $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}$, as is expected.

Unfortunately, the observed pattern from the last three examples seems to break in the following case.

If $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) = 4 $, or equivalently if
$$
\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \left(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4, 0, \ldots\right)
$$ then experimental evidence suggests that $\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) $ is given by
$$ 
\begin{align}
& \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{\lambda_4}{\left( 
\binom{\lambda_3}{k} \binom{\lambda_4}{k}k!2^{k} \right.} \right. \\ & \qquad \qquad \times \left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{3} + \lambda_{4} - k;2} \\ & \qquad \qquad \times  \left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{2} + \lambda_{3} + \lambda_{4} - k;2} \\ & \qquad \qquad \times  \left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} + k;2} \\ & \qquad \qquad \times \frac{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 - 2 \right)^{\lambda_{3} + \lambda_{4} - k;4}}{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 - 2 \right)^{\lambda_{3};4}} \\ & \qquad \qquad \times  \left. \left. \frac{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 \right)^{k;4}}{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 - 2 \right)^{\lambda_{4};4}}  \right) \right]
\end{align}
\\ \times {\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} + \lambda_{3} + \lambda_{4};2} \over \prod_{1 \le i < j \le 4}{\left( \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4  - 1 \right)^{\lambda_{i}+\lambda_{j};2}}} \\ \times \frac{\left( \lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} +\lambda_{3} + \lambda_{4} \right)!}{\lambda_{1}! \lambda_{2}! \lambda_{3}! \lambda_{4}!} 
$$
Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a symmetric form of the latter, but experimental evidence suggests that it is indeed a symmetric function in $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}, \lambda_{4}$ (wherever $\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} + \lambda_{3} + \lambda_{4}=2^{n-2}$ and $n \ge 4$).

## Questions

### #1

> How to prove the formulae for $ \operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) $ in the cases of $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) = 2,3,4 $?

### #2

> What is a symmetric form of $ \operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) $ in the case of $ \ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) = 4 $?

### #3

> What is an explicit formula for $ \operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right) $ in the case of a general $ \boldsymbol{\lambda}$?

Comment: Pedantic correction FWIW: The polynomial $Q$ is even only for $n \geq 2$, and symmetric only for $n \geq 3$.