# "Symmetrize" a (balanced) hypergeometric 4F3

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive integers such that $a+b+c+d=2^{n}$ with $n \ge 2$.

Denote
$$
N \equiv a+b+c+d=2^{n}
$$
Consider the **balanced** hypergeometric series
$$
\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}N \right)} {\left(\operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}N\right)\right)^{3}} 
\\
\times 
\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}N+c+d \right)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}N +c\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}N+d \right)}
\\
\times \operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}N+a+b \right)
\\ 
\times \operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}N-a \right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}N-b \right)
\times {}_{4}F_{3}\left(\substack{-\frac{1}{4}N,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}N-c-d,-c,-d \\ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}N-c-d, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}N+a, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}N+b} {\Biggm |} 1\right)
$$

This ${}_{4}F_{3}$ is related to a previous question - [A generalization of the difference of squares identity](https://mathoverflow.net/q/413703/), specifically to the expression (using the notation of the linked question) for $\operatorname{\mathfrak{e}}_{2\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left( \mathrm{K}_{1}^{n}, \ldots, \mathrm{K}_{2^{n-1}}^{n} \right)$ in the case of $\ell \left(\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) = 4$. In fact this ${}_{4}F_{3}$ is another way to write the expression (using the notation of the linked question)
$$
\left[\sum_{k=0}^{d}{2^{k} \binom{c}{k} \binom{d}{k}k!\left(\substack{\left( N - 1 \right)^{a + c + d - k;2}\\ \times \left( N - 1 \right)^{b + c + d - k;2} \\ \times  \left( N - 1 \right)^{a + b + k;2} }\right)} \left( \substack{ \left( N - 2 \right)^{c + d - k;4} \\ \times \left( N \right)^{k;4}} \right) \right] \times \frac{1}{\left( N - 2 \right)^{c;4}\left( N - 2 \right)^{d;4}}
$$
for $a,b,c,d,N$ as described above. Notice, then, that the ${}_{4}F_{3}$ always evaluates to a rational number.

Numerical evaluations, together with a consideration described in the linked question, suggest that the ${}_{4}F_{3}$ remains unchanged under a permutation of $a,b,c,d$ (provided that $a+b+c+d=2^{n}$ and $n \ge 2$). This leads to the following question.

> What is a **symmetric** function $f \colon \mathbb{N}^4\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f\left( a,b,c,d \right)$ agrees with the ${}_{4}F_{3}$ wherever $a+b+c+d=2^{n}$ and $n \ge 2$?

I am looking for an explicit special function expression of such a function $f$.

A starting point for a solution is using, perhaps iteratively, Whipple's balanced-${}_{4}F_{3}$-to-balanced-${}_{4}F_{3}$ transformation [(see Theorem 4.3.10 on page 112 of Hannah's dissertation)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39671766.pdf) for a free reference (mind the Pochhammer symbol for the rising factorial). Unfortunately I wasn't able to make any progress.

Comment: Your top equation breaks the page for me. Any way to make it smaller? Or split across multiple lines?

Comment: @SamHopkins I added another line. I suppose I can use the $\text{\substack}$ command, but I feel it makes things too small. Please tell me if you see more issues. The initial preview before posing the question didn't have such unfortunate line breaks.

Comment: The expressions would become considerably more readable if you would introduce and use, say, $N := 2^n = a+b+c+d$.

Comment: @FredHucht I gave it a go.

Comment: You could try the Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm, see $A=B$ (https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html).

Comment: @FredHucht I am using a Mathematica package called fastZeil from RISC which implements the WZ algorithm. Unfortunately it throws an error saying that the sum cannot be handled. I am not sure why, I'll have to investigate further. I am also using another Mathematica package called HolonomicFunctions, also by RISC, but a computation related to the $_{4}F_{3}$ has been running for a few hours now...